# Is the heat for constant pressure the same as for constant volume in the formation of nitric oxide?

Tags: gas-laws, enthalpy, pressure

In the reaction $\ce{N2 (g) + O2(g) -> 2NO (g)}$
my textbook<sup>[1]</sup>  says $q_v$ and $q_p$ are not the same, without any explanation.

I know that 
\begin{align}
\Delta U &= q_p + w\\
\Delta U &= q_p - P\Delta V\\
\Delta U &= q_p - Δn_\mathrm{gases}RT
\end{align}

I also know that 
$$\Delta U = q_v.$$

because under constant volume, work done ($-P\Delta V$) is zero, since there's no change in volume.

In the reaction mentioned, 
$$n_\mathrm{gases} = 0,$$ 
so shouldn't
$$\Delta U = q_p$$
and therefore 
$$q_p = q_v?$$

Here's a picture of question 143 in Chapter 7 of [1]. The answers say a) and d) are false:

[image: Question 143 from Chapter 7 of Petrucci et al: General Chemistry, 11th Edition (see full citation below)]

---

1. Ralph H. Petrucci, F. Geoffrey Herring, Jeffry D. Madura, Carey Bissonnette: General Chemistry: Principles and Modern Applications, 11th edition. Published by Pearson (February 23rd 2016)

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. I have updated your post with chemistry markup (more also [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945)). I have also included a real reference to the book you are using, I hope it is correct. States of aggregation should not be subscripted, it is not wrong, but the [recommendations (Sec. 2.1.)](http://pac.iupac.org/publications/pac/pdf/1982/pdf/5406x1239.pdf) are different.

Answer (score 2):

Kevin is right. In that reaction, the number of moles does not change. So carrying it at constant pressure or at constant volume does not make any difference. And $q_v$ = $q_p$

Comment: Please note that the proper term for "number of moles" is [amount of substance](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00297.html). The former would be the same as referring to the mass as "number of kilograms".